# Set width of element to combined width of siblings?

Tags: css, width, fluid, fluid-layout

Three elements are inside a fluid container in the following configuration:

```
+-----------------+
| +-----+ +-----+ |
| |  A  | |  B  | |
| +-----+ +-----+ |
| +-------------+ |
| |      C      | |
| +-------------+ |
+-----------------+
```

The width of elements A and B is 50%. The width of element C is 100%. You can see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/QDVeD/).

The right edges of the rows do not align when the width of the container is an odd number of pixels, due to rounding when computing the width of elements A and B. You can watch the edges misalign and realign while resizing the frame. The effect is exacerbated when the top row contains many more than two elements, say [ten](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/QDVeD/1/).

Instead, I would like the width of element C to be equal to the combined actual width of elements A and B, rather than the combined percentage width. Is this possible without using JavaScript or resorting to a table?

Comment: I've seen similar things done with a [Fluid 960 layout](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/), here is a example.  Open up the "16-Column Grid" to see all the different layout options and how they all lineup.

Comment: @Zachary: thanks, great resource. It looks as though they just live with the slight misalignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make the first element float left, giving it the desired width. The right one would not float, and have a default width, allowing it to stretch, filling the space left by the left. See a modification of your example for how it might work: http://jsfiddle.net/QDVeD/12/. The basics can be summed up with:

```
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}
#right {
  height: 50px;
}
```

This wouldn't scale as well as you might like for more items than two, though. The last element will usually be slightly longer than the others: http://jsfiddle.net/QDVeD/18/.

Comment: That would work for the specific case of two elements, though I was using that as a proxy for the more complex case of n elements potentially of various widths.

Comment: See the second example for a case with multiple elements. The items would not be completely evenly spaced, but you wouldn't see the misalignment on the right-hand-side.

You could easily code some PHP to reproduce this for n elements. Various widths would be more difficult, but still possible.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is that I am preserving an aspect ratio on the component elements, which would be complicated by having even slightly different widths. What I really need is for the full-width element to shrink to the component elements, though the more I investigate the more it seems like this is possible only with a table (or code).

Comment: @Nathan: As far as I know, there's no way to do it. It would require the containing element to wrap around the tiled divs, but you can only achieve that behaviour by making it inline, but the bottom div will still be misaligned. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDVeD/35/). If you really want the correct aspect ratio, then you might have to resort to tables.

Comment: I'm becoming convinced that it's not possible, because the relative widths of the component elements and the full-width element would need to reference different containing blocks.